# Configuring isort and autoflake with project.toml

Tags: python, isort, pyproject.toml, autoflake

I have a series of tools running locally and on Jenkins to check and format my Python code:

- autoflake
- isort
- black

I use `pyproject.toml` file to configure black, isort with `.isort.cfg` and autoflake with command line parameters because I haven't found any support to configure it with a configuration file.

Is there way to configure also isort and autoflake with `pyproject.toml`?

I would like to have all tools configured with just a single file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

isort configuration can be found at https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html

In general, config params are separated by underscores.  The example below will provide configuration that makes black and isort compatible, as discussed here https://copdips.com/2020/04/making-isort-compatible-with-black.html

```
[tool.isort]
multi_line_output = 3
line_length = 88
include_trailing_comma = true

[tool.black]
line_length = 88
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just move your isort config to pyproject.toml but change `[settings]` to `[tool.isort]`.

https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort#configuring-isort

I don't believe autoflake supports pyproject.toml configuration. You are welcome to open an issue on their github page.

Comment: This is why we don't allow allow URLs as answers...